# Unable to run Jasmine tests using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, testing, extjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I am using jasmine-2.3.4 and [run-jasmine.js](https://gist.github.com/barahilia/9663804). But I always get the following undefined error. I am very new to it and unsure what could be the exact command to execute my test file.

[image: Running Jasmine test file using phantomjs]

Below is my project structure:
It's an extjs based project compiled via sencha cmd. The jasmine library files are in /js/jasmine/. /js/test/test-app.js file initializes jasmine.

[image]

Below is QuestionControllerSpec.js file where the test codes are written.

[image: Test functions defined file]

The jasmine test runs perfectly fine.

[image]